# Using a template type in a swift protocol definition

Tags: generics, swift3, protocols

How can I declare an protocol in swift whose function argument types depend on the type that adopts the protocol?

Something like

```
 protocol EndianConvertible<T> {
       init( litteEndian: T );
       func litteEndian() -> T;
 }
```

Background:
I'm trying to write an stream decoder for a little endian binary stream in swift.

Part of that is a generic function

```
class ReadStream {

 var offset : Int = 0;
 var data : Data;

 func readIntLE<T : Integer>() -> T {
    var d : T = 0
    let intBits = data.withUnsafeBytes({(bytePointer: UnsafePointer<UInt8>) -> T in
        bytePointer.advanced(by: offset).withMemoryRebound(to: T.self, capacity: MemoryLayout<T>.size) { pointer in
            offset += MemoryLayout<T>.size
            return pointer.pointee
        }
    })
    d = T(littleEndian: intBits)
  }
}
```

which fails to compile as the Integer protocol does not specify that init(litteEndian: T) is available, and the obvious way to fix it seemed to have an protocol that adds that specification.

Comment: Protocols do not allow generic parameters, so for the first snippet above, you could rather use an associated type in the protocol (`protocol Foo { associatedtype T; init(litteEndian: T); /* ... */ }`).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Self in a protocol to reference the concrete type of the class/type that implements it:

```
protocol EndianConvertible
{
       init( litteEndian: Self );
       func litteEndian() -> Self;
}
```

Comment: Perfect, the reference to Self works. Now I'm at the next problem:
    
    func readUInt32() -> UInt32 {
        return readIntLE()
    }

With only the definition above I get an error 'Generic parameter T could not be infered

    'extension UInt32 : EndianConvertible {
    } 

results in 'Type UInt32 does not conform to EndianConvertible'